# Script which run open SSL on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssl, openssl, sh

I wrote an .sh script which run openssl command on windows:

```
openssl s_client -connect [ADRESS]:8883 -cert ./device.cert.pem -key ./device.key.pem
read;
```

**The motivation:**
There are sensors that are installed on the ceiling, which connects to the AWS cloud. I would like to send a test tool ahead of the physical sensors arriving at a site, this tool will run on the network that the sensors are going to be deployed later on - and run open SSL.
The sensors have Linux OS and they run open SSL - I would like to have a windows tool which does the same. it will identify proxies, blocked ports and verify that the connection is possible.

**The problem:**
The script requires that SSL will be installed on the windows machine, is there any way to avoid this dependency? perhaps include some open ssl library (zip, jar etc.) ?

Comment: My suggestion would usually be "use SslStream from PowerShell", but it's unclear that would be sufficient. Can you edit your question to provide more detail about your use case, please?

Comment: Thanks Roger, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

There are two critical activities of installers, one is to copy/unpack the binaries for local execution and the other is to add one or more directories to the path environment variable so that your script can simply invoke `openssl` for instance, rather than having to know the exact path to its location. Adding registry cruft is another thing that can happen in support of poorly designed applications.

If the tool is "xcopy installable", as-in, doesn't require registry cruft to operate, then you can copy the bits to a location of your choosing and execute them from there. Another option is to invoke them directly from a file share on the network, but this can be difficult to configure properly with some applications. Beware of data/config files laying next to binaries. If the app can be started pointing to local config and data, you're good to go, otherwise, you'll wind up copying the bits locally.

I generally designate a local user specific directory to be used as a file cache and copy the bits there if the correct version isn't already present. Your scripts can then look in the cache first and only copy bits across the network on first use.

Basically, you can't run the application if it's not present on the machine. Your options are:

1. Error message when openssl not installed.
2. Provide an option to install openssl when you detect that is missing.
3. If possible, xcopy install the bits you need.